While Hierarchical namespace enabled cannot upload blob with metadata hdi_isfolder
I am using Azure Datastorage Gen2 and I have came across problem that I cannot create virtual directory when Hierarchical namespace option is enabled.
If I try to do this
        const std::string blobContent= "";

        auto blockBlobClient= std::make_shared<Azure::Storage::Blobs::BlockBlobClient>(m_container->GetBlobClient(blobName).AsBlockBlobClient());

        std::vector<uint8_t> buffer(blobContent.begin(), blobContent.end());
        blockBlobClient->UploadFrom(buffer.data(), buffer.size());

        Azure::Storage::Metadata blobMetadata= {{"hdi_isfolder", "true"}};
        blockBlobClient->SetMetadata(blobMetadata);

I am getting error *Error: 400 One of the HTTP headers specified in the request is not supported.
*
But isn't that a way how to create a virtual directory?
Can someone please explain me what am I doing wrong?
Thanks!
I have tried to create virtual directory in ADLS Gen2 blob storage
I got Error: 400 One of the HTTP headers specified in the request is not supported
I expected folder to be created without any problems

Check the below answer.


to create virtual directory in ADLS Gen2 blob storage

You can use the below code to create directory in Azure Data Lake Gen2 blob storage using C++.
To create directory, you need to install azure datalake gen2 package using below command.
vcpkg install azure-storage-files-datalake-cpp

Code:
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <azure/storage/files/datalake.hpp>


int main()
{
    using namespace Azure::Storage::Files::DataLake;

    const std::string fileSystemName = "test";
    const std::string directoryName = "sample-directory";
 
    const std::string connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=venkat78901;AccountKey=52ZxzzzEZCvozzzzzzzzzzAStAvgrmA==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";

    auto fileSystemClient
        = DataLakeFileSystemClient::CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, fileSystemName);
    fileSystemClient.CreateIfNotExists();

    // Create a directory.
    auto directoryClient = fileSystemClient.GetDirectoryClient(directoryName);
    directoryClient.Create();

    std::cout << "Directory created: " << directoryName << std::endl;

    return 0;
}


The above executed and created directory in my container.
Output:
Directory created: sample-directory

Portal:

Reference:
azure-storage-files-datalake: Azure Storage Files Data Lake Client Library for C++ (azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net)

That means when Hierarchical namespace options is enabled, it is not supported to create a block block with metadata using BlobServiceClient?
Or it just cannot create a blob with specific metadata (reserved words)?

The above package is designed for authenticate with data lake gen 2(hierarchical namespace enabled) storage accounts.

Refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.files.datalake.datalakefileclient.setmetadata?view=azure-dotnet to set metadata using datalake service client.

It kind of did it, but I still want to use BlobServiceClient and BlockBlobClient.
Is there a way I can read that header, to check what is not supported in it?
Error: 400 One of the HTTP headers specified in the request is not supported. 
One of the HTTP headers specified in the request is not supported. 
RequestId:1327839e-201e-003a-13bd-ddb25c000000 
Time:2024-07-24T11:37:29.9697412Z 
Request ID: 1327839e-201e-003a-13bd-ddb25c000000

Yes. Using blob service client you cannot able to create virtual directory.

Can you please send me a document where it says that? @Venkatesan

Container client doesn't have create directory function instead you can able to create a directory by uploading with file name.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-upload#upload-a-block-blob-from-a-local-file-path BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(<foldername>/file,txt);

I was never trying to do that, but to create a blob and add specific metadata to it, which is not supported, and on all this links you have sent me, there no official statement that it is adding metadata tag "hdi_isfolder" is not supported with ADLS Gen2 with Hierarchical Namespace option enabled. I am not blaming you @Venkatesan, it is just an observation. Also I forgot to mention I am using Azure SDK for cpp.
Also one thing to add, this option worked with azure.storage 7.5 deprecated library. And this means it does not support regression, right?

empty blob + metadata (hdi_isfolder) = virtual directory? Or I completely misunderstood this?

Yep I think so have you tried with my code to do the same?

I have tried your code, but It does not work out of box, I have to adapt url to dfs, to check if fileSystem exists,... But it will work for sure, this is same as adls2 example.
Thanks @Venkatesan Anyway it is quite tricky to align all this Azure "features".

It worked, had to update link from blob to dfs and it works fine, thanks!
